# Drupal 8 in Realtime

Tags: node.js, server, real-time, drupal-8

I am Using Drupal 8.9 with nginx and MS-SQL,

I need to make my whole project in Realtime, without refreshing the page I need to update the content. In my project there is always content coming from the backend, via REST API. So whenever the content comes i have to refresh the page i.e. every minute, instead of that whenever the content comes it should get updated in the page automatically without refresh i.e. in Real time

First I used Nodejs Integration module https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs , with that I was only able to make the " [Recent Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spnNG.png) " real time. I need the whole project to be in Real time.

How can I make my Whole project Real time ? Is there any other way I can approach this  situation ? Can anyone Help?

Can I write custom module for the same? then how should I approach this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a javascript framework for your frontend, instead of javascript on the back end. There's a lot of interesting stuff happening around React and Drupal with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) or [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com).

None of this will solve your problem quickly, as there's a lot to learn to use these effectively. But with javascript on the front end you can develop a web application that can intermittently query your backend as you require.

Don't forget about caching.